# html5 email field validation issue with .at domain

Tags: html

So we've been using HTML5 required field attributes and have changed our email field type from 'text' to 'email'.

Visitors with .at(austria) domain names are being prompted 'Did you mean...' which raised a complaint.

I'm new to HTML5 and believe it is browser based. Who can be contacted to get .at domains on the whitelist?

Comment: I would suggest, putting your input validation on the back end, if you let me know what you are using (php or vb) I will give you some code.

Comment: Please provide code example in here or jsfiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/atwellpub/dgk6tbn6/

Comment: This was an error inside my own codebase. Topic needs deleting.

Answer (score 0):

Functionality like this is almost always implemented by the makers of the browser that was used.